# How to listen to thousands of imap idle inboxes via spring/amqp/rabbit

Tags: imap, jakarta-mail, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Use case is to have a server connect to thousands of users email accounts and sniff incoming mail in java preferably with java mail and spring integration/amqp/rabbit mq type scalable infrastructure.. And imap idle type connections and add server processing nodes as needed.

Single inbound channel is easy with imap idle inbound adapter.. You could configure few in XML. But if you need a persistent listener/imapidlechannel adapters queue of thousands of these adapters and Needed to add new user connection dynamically for server processing.. This would be a challenge. Also need fault taulerance that if the java listener dies or server reboots all these listeners and their configuration also reboot vs rebuilding thousands of these connections and recovery if some connections loose their idle receive capability without rebuilding all user connections for the idle receiving.

Any ideas welcome as searched a lot however could not find anything? This seems to be a significant scalability issue about e mail receive connections open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the IMAP IDLE command to listen for new messages using JavaMail, you'll need one thread per mailbox, which is likely to impact your scalability.  Even keeping thousands of connections open might be an issue.

You don't say how quickly you need to react to new messages.  Unless you have near real time requirements, it might be better to poll a subset of mailboxes every so often, eventually cycling through all the mailboxes.

You'll need to deal with the fault tolerance issues yourself, using checkpointing or transactions or whatever seems appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thats kind of a conclusion I was drawing...need some input on best way to build resiliance and scale with amqp/spring infrastructure.

The flow would be
- build list of all users to poll and paginate through n
- put first n on a queue and process in amqp distributed environment
- put next n till complete
- recreate the cycle

The challenge with this is messaging and state management of the process via spring-integration and persistence capabilities. What would be the best approach to pull the plug and have the state of processing recover from where it left off without handcrafting lot of code?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the user experience does desire near realtime type delay to see a email pop-in, so question is could servers be added on the fly in distributed environment as users get added, where these n process with x threads each could perpetually listen? like dynamic connection pools per server and their affinity and knowledge of which users they are connecting forever? maybe some kind of persistent cache for the user attributes, but the dynamic distributed node pools is a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to perhaps take a look at something like Akka with actors performing the async io.  You'll need to ditch the JavaMail package and parse the imap commands yourself but there's lots of packages out there to do that.  Would love to hear if you had a better solution.